# Windows bar wont auto hide

Tags: windows

One thing ive experienced with all windows versions and still do is the taskbar poping up and staying up. Its supposed to auto hide if there are not notifications. But sometimes it kind of gets stuck? I look through everyting if there is an application needing attention but cant see anything. Lock taskbar is not enabled. Is this a known issue or am i missunderstanding something maybe? I cant beleive it can be a bug since its been like this through all windows editions.

Answer (score 0):

This just kinda happens with the taskbar sometimes, What has helped me in the past is pressing the windows key twice and if that doesn't work toggling the "Lock the taskbar" option seems to help.

I Just stopped hiding the taskbar because of this.

Comment: Yeah I know how to reset it. It just baffles me that this is still a thing after about 20 years of Windows?